# How do I transfer ranges containing formatting information from pages in a word doc to a new word doc in random order?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My wife is a professor, and I found out she's been manually creating randomized versions of her tests (to reduce cheating) *by hand* for years, along with all of the other faculty in her department.  She uses Word 2007 and 2010 to write her tests, so I set about writing a VBA macro to do this tedious process for her.

Her tests include images, lists, and other formatting, so straight text copying won't work.  All questions that reference the same images are on the same page, otherwise each question gets it's own page.  The first page contains instructions and needs to be included at the beginning of a randomized test doc, but all other pages need to be randomized in a new document.  After the randomization process, I am removing page breaks so that questions are neatly on as few pages as possible.

So far I haven't been able to transfer Ranges taken from the Page collection to the new document without losing the formatting information.  I've googled all over the place, but I haven't found any indications of what I'm doing wrong yet.

My code thus far:

```
Sub CreateTestVersions()

Dim ThisDoc As Document
Dim NewDoc As Document
Dim Pgs As pages
Dim Question As Range

Let Skip = 1 'Number of pages to skip randomizing

Set ThisDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
Set NewDoc = Documents.Add 'Create new document
Set Pgs = ThisDoc.Windows(1).Panes(1).pages 'Pages collection

ReDim Questions(1 To Pgs.Count - Skip) As Range

For p = 1 To Skip 'Add skipped pages to begining of new document
    NewDoc.Content = NewDoc.Content & Pgs(p).Rectangles(1).Range
Next

' Add questions to an array of ranges
For q = LBound(Questions) To UBound(Questions)
    Set Question = Pgs(q + Skip).Rectangles(1).Range

    'Keep questions on a single page, don't split accross pages
    Question.Paragraphs.KeepTogether = True

    ' All lists, text formatting, etc. is lost for some reason
    Set Questions(q) = Question ' Needs fixed
Next

'Randomization needs to happen here

'Add randomized questions to new document
For q = LBound(Questions) To UBound(Questions)
    NewDoc.Content = NewDoc.Content & Questions(q)
Next

'Remove page breaks
With NewDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = "^m"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

I'm using the Questions array because I figure that will be easier to randomize, especially when I expand this code to generate more than one version.  I'd also like to avoid using Select, Copy, Paste if at all possible.

Any insight on why I'm losing formatting and what the proper approach should be is appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to do this will be Copy and Paste, unfortunately. You could experiment with Range.FormattedText, but as I understand it that only includes formatted text, not images and other information. Is there a reason you don't want to use Copy/Paste (I have my own reasons for not being overly fond, but I don't think they apply here)?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't paste into an array, and I need to be able to generate multiple randomized versions of the test.  So copy/paste doesn't work for this case (as far as I know).  I did manage to get this to work using InsertFile() and creating ranged bookmarks around each question, which preserves all the formatting/images etc.  Appreciate the comment.  If you think my question has merit, would you mind bumping it up to at least 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to get this to work using InsertFile and adding ranged bookmarks around each question.  Here is the finished product.  Hopefully it will help some other people out!

```
Sub CreateTestVersions()

Dim ThisDoc As Document
Dim NewDocs() As Document
Dim Pgs As pages
Dim Question As Range
Dim skip As Variant
Dim versions As Variant
Dim Vers() As Integer
Dim qList As String
Dim numQs As Integer
Dim bound() As String
Dim fileName() As String
Dim pages As Integer
Dim minPages As Integer
Dim tryAgain As Boolean
Dim all As Range

Set ThisDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
Set Pgs = ThisDoc.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).pages 'Pages collection

'Number of pages to skip randomizing
skip = InputBox( _
    "Each question should be on its own page, " _
    & "unless that question shares a connection with another " _
    & "(e.g. they share an image reference).  You can separate " _
    & "them using CTRL-Enter or Insert Page Break." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "How many pages belong at the beginning of every version " _
    & "(instructions, personal data, etc.)?", "Question", 1)

If skip = "" Then Exit Sub

versions = InputBox("How many versions would you like to produce?", "Question", 4)

If versions = "" Then Exit Sub

numQs = Pgs.Count - skip

qList = InputBox(numQs & " question pages detected. Please list which questions" _
    & " you want to use, with ranges denoted with dashes and gaps by commas" _
    & " (e.g. 1-5, 9, 12-20).", "Question", "1-" & numQs)

If qList = "" Then Exit Sub

ReDim NewDocs(1 To versions) As Document
ReDim Vers(1 To versions) As Integer
For v = 1 To versions
    'Create new document(s)
    Set NewDocs(v) = Documents.Add
    Vers(v) = v
Next

ReDim Indexes(1 To numQs) As Long
qList = Replace(qList, " ", "")
RangeList = Split(qList, ",")
numQs = 0
For Each rng In RangeList
    bound = Split(rng, "-")
    For i = bound(LBound(bound)) To bound(UBound(bound))
        numQs = numQs + 1
        Indexes(numQs) = i
    Next
Next

ReDim Preserve Indexes(1 To numQs) As Long
ReDim Questions(1 To numQs) As Range

' Add questions to an array of ranges
For Each q In Indexes
    If (Not ThisDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Question " & q)) Then
        ThisDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Question" & q, _
                          Pgs(q + skip).Rectangles(1).Range
    End If
Next

minPages = Pgs.Count
Randomize
Do
    For Each v In Vers
        'Clear new document in case we are retrying for a shorter version
        Set all = NewDocs(v).Content
        all.WholeStory
        all.Select
        Selection.Delete
        'Add skipped pages to begining of new document
        If (Not ThisDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Introduction")) Then
            ThisDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Introduction", _
                ThisDoc.Range(Pgs(1).Rectangles(1).Range.Start, _
                              Pgs(skip).Rectangles(1).Range.End)
        End If
        NewDocs(v).Content.InsertFile ThisDoc.FullName, "Introduction"

        'Generate random indexs
        For i = numQs To 2 Step -1
            r = Int(Rnd() * (i - 2)) + 1
            temp = Indexes(r)
            Indexes(r) = Indexes(i)
            Indexes(i) = temp
        Next i

        'Add randomized questions to new document
        For q = LBound(Questions) To UBound(Questions)
            i = Indexes(q)
            Set Question = NewDocs(v).Content
            Question.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            Question.InsertFile ThisDoc.FullName, "Question" & i
            Set Question = NewDocs(v).Range(Question.Start, NewDocs(v).Range.End)
            Question.Paragraphs.KeepWithNext = True
            NewDocs(v).Bookmarks.Add "Question" & i, Question
        Next

        'Remove page breaks
        With NewDocs(v).Content.Find
            .Text = "^m"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With

        'Group questions within pages, not accross them
        For Each Bookmark In NewDocs(v).Bookmarks
            Bookmark.Range.Paragraphs.Last.KeepWithNext = False
        Next

        pages = NewDocs(v).Windows(1).Panes(1).pages.Count
        If pages < minPages Then minPages = pages
    Next

    ' If all pages are not minimum length then try again
    tryAgain = False
    For Each v In Vers
        pages = NewDocs(v).Windows(1).Panes(1).pages.Count
        If pages > minPages Then tryAgain = True
    Next
Loop While tryAgain

For Each v In Vers
    'Save Document
    fileName = Split(ThisDoc.Name, ".")
    file = fileName(0)
    ext = fileName(1)
    NewDocs(v).SaveAs2 _
            fileName:=file & " Version " & v & "." & ext, _
            CompatibilityMode:=wdCurrent
Next
ThisDoc.Activate
End Sub
```